# Regex: Match a pattern within quoted texts

Tags: regex

Text is

```
lemma A:
"
 abx K() bc
"

// comment lemma B
lemma B:
"
 abx bc sdsf
"


lemma C:
"
 abfdfx K() bc
"


lemma D:
"
 abxsf bc
"
```

I want to find the lemmas which contain K() inside its following quoted text. I have tried Perl regex `(?s)^[ ]*lemma.*?"(?!").*?K\(` but it overlaps two lemmas. The output should be: `lemma A: "..."` and `lemma C: "..."`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
(?s)^[ ]*lemma[^"]*"[^"]*?K\(
```

`[^"]` means "any character but `"`"

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/PFEkWd/1)

Answer (score 1):

If the double quotes are at the start of the string, you can match a newline and then the double quote.

Then match any char except the double quote until you match `K(`

```
^[ ]*lemma\b.*\R"[^"]*K\(
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[ ]*lemma\b` Match optional spaces and `lemma`
- `.*\R` Match the rest of the line and a newline
- `"[^"]*` Match `"` followed by optional chars other than `"`
- `K\(` Match `K(`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AKonAe/1)